# Runtime exception while creating Blob

Tags: java, oracle

Trying to create BLOB object using `BLOB.createTemporary(connection, false, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION)` ,But getting Class Cast Exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.cpdsadapter.ConnectionImpl cannot be cast to
>   oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.

I tried following suggestions but still same error .[Apache Commons DBCP connection object problem, Thread: ClassCastException in org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489514/apache-commons-dbcp-connection-object-problem-thread-classcastexception-in-org)

Some one please suggest me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please show relevant code, and complete stack trace.

Comment: BLOB blob = BLOB.createTemporary(delConn, false, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);  Exception :java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.cpdsadapter.ConnectionImpl cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Comment: So your program is one line long?  What is the type of "delConn"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle `BLOB.createTemporary()` method expects the `Connection` parameter to be a `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection` object, but connections from Tomcat are managed by DBCP, so the `connection` is wrapped in a DBCP class (`org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper`).

You either need to unwrap it to get the real Oracle connection object, or stop using the Oracle `BLOB`.

Just use the JDBC methods: `Blob blob = connection.createBlob()`

**Update**

The JDBC `Blob` is an interface. There are no implementing classes in the JDK, so you'll always get a DBMS specific implementation. If needed, you *can* cast to `OracleBlob`, which is also an interface, that provides additional Oracle-specific methods.

---

Interesting javadoc for [OracleBlob](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleBlob.html):

> Generally any new code should avoid the direct use of the class `BLOB`. For variable declarations use the interface `Blob` or this interface as required. Instead of the static methods `BLOB.createTemporary(java.sql.Connection, boolean, int)` and `BLOB.empty_lob()` please use `Connection.createBlob()` and `BLOB.getEmptyBLOB()` respectively.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, How to unwrap it.

Comment: Is there any difference in using JDBC Blob over Oracle BLOB

Comment: First option: Don't. You'll be casting to internal Tomcat classes, so your code will only work with Tomcat, and may break on next Tomcat version.

Comment: JDBC Blob will work with all DBMS's. Don't know if there are any negative sides.

Comment: I tried Blob getting exception : Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.createBlob()Ljava/sql/Blob;
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.createBlob(DelegatingConnection.java:571)

Comment: Your JDBC driver is too old. Upgrade it. `createBlob` was added in Java 6, so you need a Java 6 compatible version. Better yet, use the latest JDBC driver version that support your Java version.

Comment: Thanks,I can't change the version simply, Is there anyway to resolve this issue without changing driver?

Comment: Maybe: Try to cast connection to `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection` and call `getDelegate()` or `getInnermostDelegate()`. If they work and return an `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection`, then you are good to go, but the code will *only* work with Tomcat and may not work on different Tomcat versions. --- It would be *much better* to use a JDBC Driver version that supports the Java version you're running on.

Comment: I tried ,but returning null,so Both getDelegate() and getInnermostDelegate both not working

Comment: Then your only option is to upgrade your driver. *Or* stop using `Blob`/`BLOB` and just use a `byte[]`, if not insanely huge.

Comment: I am using ojdbc14.jar, Which one is right version to support this functionality

Comment: Download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html#). Get either the latest (best option) or the one matching you Database version. The `12.1.0.2` version has a driver for Java 6 (`ojdbc6.jar`) and Java 7 (`ojdbc7.jar`). Use the 7 if you're on Java 8.

Comment: By seeing version,I am using latest version.this is very strange issue.

Comment: If you call `conn.getMetaData().getDriverVersion()`, it prints 12.1.0.2 ? --- Anyway, you said you were using `ojdbc14.jar`, which is an old version for Java 1.4! Since you could compile with `createBlob()`, I know you're at least on Java 6.